# Spectra S3 Java CLI (DS3) difficulty verifying checksum

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

We have a SpectraLogic BlackPearl+T950 which uses S3 style commands to put/get/sync etc.

To access the Spectra flavour of S3 commands we use a [Java CLI client](https://developer.spectralogic.com/java-command-line-interface-cli-reference-and-examples/) to perform these operations.

Supposedly there's an option to validate checksums:

> --checksum
>
> Validate checksum values.

However when we run the CLI with that option we just get this error:

> Error (UnrecognizedOptionException): Unrecognized option: --checksum

Q: Does anyone have experience with this sort of setup and checking the validity of the checksums of the retrieved files?

---

Other Clients:

The EON Browser is very clunky (only loading 30 files at a time) so not particularly great, plus I'm not certain if it validates the checksum either.

I've tried other 'S3' clients such as [s3Express](https://www.s3express.com/), [s3Browser](https://s3browser.com/), [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/), and [s3cmd](https://s3tools.org/s3cmd), but they either won't accept a custom endpoint, or they don't work if the file being retrieved is not in the BlackPearl cache (ie Just on tape). s3Express & s3cmd also cost money to use fully, so they're kind of out anyway!

Checksum Note:

s3cmd seemed to validate checksums pretty well when the files were in the cache. I was thinking of using the Java CLI to do the get/sync and then use s3cmd to do the verify, but I can't figure out how to get it to ***just*** verify checksums - it wants to do a put/get/sync (which fail due to cache issue)

---

Alternate:
The issue with the s3cmd is that when the file is only on tape (and not in cache too) it seems to get a redirect of some sort and then times out the file with these errors (instead of waiting for the tape to be loaded and the file transferred to cache):

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
> TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, NoneType found

If anyone knows how to get s3cmd to work with retrieval from tape, I will accept that answer if there's no solution to the DS3 Java CLI checksum issue.